# Wildcard in SOQL python

Tags: python, sql, salesforce

I am trying to query from salesforce using python using simple_salesforce package. When I do wildcard, it is throwing me Malfunction error.

```
soql = """SELECT {} FROM Contact where LastModifiedDate like "%2020-06-16%" """.format(','.join(field_names)) 
results = sf.query_all(soql)
```

Error

```
line 1:1374 no viable alternative at character
```

Comment: Did you try double '%' (`%%`)?

Answer (score 1):

The date filter is wrong, This field is of type DateTime, not Date

You need to end up with something like

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email 
FROM Contact 
WHERE DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) = 2020-06-15
```

Or

```
WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2020-06-15T00:00:00Z
    AND LastModifiedDate < 2020-06-16T00:00:00Z
```

There's a bunch of [date conversion functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) and special [literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) (not-really-constants) like `TODAY, YESTERDAY, LAST_N_DAYS:123`